# In Android 4.x API level 14, can you set the Action Bar Tab width?

Tags: android, tabs, width, android-actionbar

I have set images for each tab using tab.setIcon and I have created a custom style for my tabs , but how can I make them a narrower width?  Currently they are wider than the image they were set to use and also scroll because they are too wide for the screen.  I would prefer not to use ActionBarSherlock since I don't need it's support for OS versions below 4.0.

Comment: Is ActionBarSherlock the only way?

Comment: At this point I will try ActionBar Sherlock and report back.

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct (and you're probably already doing that, but I'll suggest anyway) would be to play with `android:actionBarTabStyle` in your theme, making sure that it's setting padding to 0dp:

```
<item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
<item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
```

Comment: Yes, I did that, but it still seems to have a built in minimum width beyond the padding.